# RequireJS + Backbone without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, zepto

I'm trying to use RequireJS, here is my config file :

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/scripts",
  paths: {
    zepto: "zepto.min",
    underscore: "underscore.min",
    backbone: "backbone.min"
  },
  shim: {
    zepto: {
      exports: "$"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ["underscore", "zepto"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    }
  }
});
```

And this is my app.js :

```
require(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  console.log('loaded!');
});
```

This works fine, but I don't know why RequireJS is trying to load jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **Backbone** requires module called **jquery** (look at top of `backbone.js`) file.

```
  // Set up Backbone appropriately for the environment. Start with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });
```

and You haven't defined this module.

To hack this use `zepto` as `jquery`:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/scripts",
  paths: {
    jquery: "zepto.min",
    underscore: "underscore.min",
    backbone: "backbone.min"
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: "$"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    }
  }
});
```

And second: `shim` only works with **non-amd** modules. Backbone is AMD module.

Comment: Backbone no longer requires jquery, see https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Using-Backbone-without-jQuery for how to run without it

Comment: @ivani Look at to of `backbone.js` file (v. 1.2.3). Backbone needs module called `jquery`

Comment: Thanks @TomaszJakubRup ! I didn't know about this hack, very nice.